# What is the difference between App and add-on in Google marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I need to help with understanding if there's a difference between developing an app or an add-on for the Google Workspace Marketplace.
From documentation I found that an app can only support one app for example Gmail, while the add-on can be used cross-app. Meaning also on sheets, slides, or whatever google app I choose.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o154A.png)
https://support.google.com/marketplace/answer/172391?hl=en

Not sure what is the difference and if there's a difference.

Comment: In my mind apps can have access to any of the core functions and api's and can deal with several different google products.  The one difference between most of my personally used apps and an  addon is that I don't get them verified by google because I or a very small group of selected people who all are members of a shared drive ever get to use them and they are all willing to authenticate them.